# Как вывести все данные из таблицы в Unity?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, unity3d

Как вывести все подряд данные из таблицы в Unity? Есть такой код, но выдает ошибку:

// `Cannot implicitly convert type string' to UnityEngine.UI.Text'`

// `Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.UI.Text' to string'`

```
cmd_db = new SqliteCommand ("SELECT * from Users", con_db);
    rdr = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
    {
      txt = txt + rdr [0].ToString ()+" ," + rdr [1].ToString ()+", " + rdr [2].ToString (); 
      text.text = txt;
    }
```

Так выводит последнюю запись из таблицы:

```
cmd_db = new SqliteCommand ("SELECT * from Users", con_db);
    rdr = cmd_db.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read ()) 
    {
      text.text = rdr[1].ToString ();
      text1.text = rdr[2].ToString ();
      text2.text = rdr[3].ToString ();
    }
```

Comment: Когда пишете вопрос, особенно где какой-то код выдает ошибку, то иногда (**всегда**) надо писать её текст, на какой строке выдает и пр. Так легче понять в какую сторону копать.......и почему в 1-ом примере rdr 0,1,2  а во втором 1,2,3 ? И куда пытаешься вывести?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский индекс не имеет значения, просто столбцы.
Ошибка в первом примере в конкатенации строк +.
Вывожу в Text....

Иначе говоря мне нужно вывести все содержимое таблицы, сделать что-то типа "таблицы лидеров" может конечно выводить нужно не в text, но подходящего UI не наблюдаю....

Comment: Ну естественно последнюю запись выдает, так как ты перезаписываешь данные в ui text  на новые каждый цикл. По первому надо код ошибки.

Comment: @nika.brown09 так какая ошибка?) добавь в вопрос

Comment: вот такие ошибки сейчас
 1)Cannot implicitly convert type string' to UnityEngine.UI.Text'

 2)Cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.UI.Text' to string'

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  в какой элемент UI выводить данные? у меня был text, туда выводится только одно значение, т.е. данные одного столбца не влезут в один элемент text.

Comment: @nika.brown09 у тебя txt это string или UI.Text ? Варианта 2, делать ui.text для каждой записи и складывать как в 1ом варианте, либо делать ui.text  для каждой записи и ячейки столбца(столбы складывать как во втором варианте)  Добавить индекс и массивы из ui.text, text2[i].text = rdr[3].ToString (); и с каждым циклом i++. Если все записи надо, либо динамически добавлять ui.text со скроллом, либо страницы делать по 10 записей, либо только первые 10 лучших например выводить.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ делаю так, пишет все в одну строку без переноса строки

`text1.text += rdr[1].ToString ()+"\r\n";
   text1.text = text1.text.Remove (text1.text.Length - 2, 2);`

Comment: @nika.brown09 вообще если писать `text.text = "sdfdkjshf \n sdf hsdfsdf \n sdfhj dskjf \n dsf sdf "` - то должно выводиться в несколько строк, а не в одну...зачем делаешь `Remove (text1.text.Length - 2, 2);`? ....... вот в этой строке: `txt = txt + rdr [0].ToString ()....` переменная `txt` - это строка? .... такое ощущение что ты что-то упростила и не всё показала. ибо конкатенация строк вполне себе работает, а в `text.text` вполне себе можно присвоить строку......

Comment: ... а вообще для таблицы надо либо делать через OnGUI (старый способ) и его GridLayout, либо через UI и его компоненты (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GridLayoutGroup.html и пр.) создав, например, префаб горизонтальной линии и в цикле его инстанциирования с новыми данными

Comment: @АлексейШиманский должно но не срабатывает почему то, а делала я по этому примеру http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread155437.html